# .hidden folders not showing in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, file-management, hidden

I have a Samsung s5 running Android v6.0.1 and a Samsung s9+ running v8.0.0.  Neither are rooted.

When I plug either phone into PC running Windows 8.1, I can't see any `.hidden` folders on the phones via Windows File Explorer.

Folders that don't start with a `.` are visible.

I've made sure that the phones are connected in USB "File Transfer Mode"

And that Windows File explorer is configured to show hidden files.

I know I used to be able to see all folders, even the `.hidden` ones on the s5 at least.

I've tried clearing the Media Storage app cache, and rebooting both the phone and the PC.

Any other solutions to get access back.

Comment: Rename the folder, use `adb pull`, different file manager e.g. Solid Explorer etc many options.

Comment: If your MTP database (/data/data/com.android.providers.media/databases/external.db) doesn't contain hidden file entries, you won't see those on PC. It depends on how Media Storage updates that database, but I haven't gone through source code of the app.